# Variation Confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> *If $a\propto c$ and $b\propto c$, then*$$\begin{align*} & (a\pm b)\propto c\\ & \sqrt{ab}\propto c\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

Also

> *If $a\propto b$ and $c\propto d$, then we have*$$\begin{align*} & ac\propto bd\\ & \frac ac\propto\frac bd\end{align*}\tag{2}$$

**Question:** I need help proving the two theorems

For the first theorem, I know that I can rewite $a\propto c$ and $b\propto c$ as $a=mc$ and $b=nc$ respectivately. But adding them together, I get $(a+b)\propto (m+n)c$ but I'm stuck because I don't know what to do afterwards.

Comment: From $(a+b) =(m+n)c$ you can conclude $(a+b) \propto c$.

Comment: @angryavian Wait, $(a+b)=(m+n)c$? Why do we have that? (I have no formal training in variation. Sorry if this seems obviously stupid...)

Comment: You wrote $a=mc$ and $b=nc$. Then $(a+b)=(m+n)c$.

Comment: I've found it much easier to convert everything to good old fashioned equal signs and go from there. That is, once you write $a = mc$ and $b = nc$, you are dealing with absolute equality (for some $m$ and some $n$ that you don't know of, of course). Dealing with equal signs is something that you hopefully have more experience with and can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, you can say $ a+b = (m+n)c $ as you defined m and n yourself, so that $a=mc$ and $b=nc$

For the second, same idea. Substitute $a=mc$ and $b=nc$ under the root.

The third is exactly the same approach. $a=mb$ and $c=nd$ and you'll almost instantly get what you're looking for.